# What's a $\mathcal{C}^{-1}$ function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Context: http://www.hairer.org/notes/Regularity.pdf, page 8 (between equations 2.9 and 2.10).

> given a distribution $\eta \in \mathcal{C}^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha > -r = |\inf A|, $ [...]

This implies that $\alpha$ is allowed to be negative, and so that $\eta$ may be in, for example, $\mathcal{C}^{-1}$. What does this mean? I've never come across $\mathcal{C}^k$ spaces with negative exponents.

Second, why does the author call $\eta$ a distribution? My understanding is that a distribution is an element of the continuous dual space of a function space. Here, however, it looks like $\eta$ is an element of the function space $\mathcal{C}^{\alpha}$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.3 of that same reference you can find the definition of $\mathcal{C}^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0$.